# Execution order of of static blocks in an Enum type  w.r.t to constructor

Tags: java, enums, jls

This is from Effective Java :

```
// Implementing a fromString method on an enum type
  private static final Map<String, Operation> stringToEnum
      = new HashMap<String, Operation>();

  static { // Initialize map from constant name to enum constant
    for (Operation op : values())
      stringToEnum.put(op.toString(), op);
  }

  // Returns Operation for string, or null if string is invalid
  public static Operation fromString(String symbol) {
    return stringToEnum.get(symbol);
  }
```

> Note that the Operation constants are put into the stringToEnum map
>   from a static block that runs after the constants have been created.
>   Trying to make each constant put itself into the map from its own
>   constructor would cause a compilation error. This is a good thing,
>   because it would cause a NullPointerException if it were legal. Enum
>   constructors aren’t permitted to access the enum’s static fields,
>   except for compile-time constant fields. This restriction is necessary
>   because these static fields have not yet been initialized when the
>   constructors run.

My question is regarding the line :

> "Note that the Operation constants are put into the stringToEnum map 
>   from a static block that runs after the constants have been created" .

I thought the static block gets executed before the constructor runs. The are actually executed   during  class load time.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028219/are-there-any-guarantees-in-jls-about-order-of-execution-static-initialization-b

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I understand your question as: why is there a guarantee that the enum constants will be initialised before the static block is run. The answer is given in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), and a specific example is given in [#8.9.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e12220), with the following explanation:

> static initialization occurs top to bottom.

and the enums constants are implicitly final static and are declared before the static initializer block.

**EDIT**

The behaviour is not different from a normal class. The code below prints:

```
In constructor: PLUS
PLUS == null MINUS == null

In constructor: MINUS
PLUS != null MINUS == null

In static initialiser
PLUS != null MINUS != null

In constructor: after static
PLUS != null MINUS != null
```

```
public class Operation {

    private final static Operation PLUS = new Operation("PLUS");
    private final static Operation MINUS = new Operation("MINUS");

    static {
        System.out.println("In static initialiser");
        System.out.print("PLUS = " + PLUS);
        System.out.println("\tMINUS = " + MINUS);
    }

    public Operation(String s) {
        System.out.println("In constructor: " + s);
        System.out.print("PLUS = " + PLUS);
        System.out.println("\tMINUS = " + MINUS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Operation afterStatic = new Operation ("after static");
    }    
}
```

Comment: say the Operation represents the operation of a Calculator . And the constants(PLUS,MINUS,DIVIDE,MULTIPLY) will only be created  after the constructor runs . So I am confused as to how the constants can be initialized before the constructor runs .The implicit static final fields that holds the constants may be created before the constructor but they can only be assigned after the constructor runs .

Comment: each constant (PLUS, MINUS...) will be initialized after their respective constructor has been run. The order of execution, if you want, will be: `PLUS = new Operation(...); MINUS = new Operation(...); ... ; static block`

Comment: That's why Bloch says that if you try to populate the map from the constructors because the constants have not been initialised until all the constructors have finished running.

Comment: so the constructors actually run before the static block . This means Enum behavior is separate from other normal Classes. Right ?

Comment: No it's not - I have added an example with a normal class to my answer. The enum runs in a similar way except that some of it is implicit.

Comment: The example shows that PLUS and MINUS can be null in the constructor, but are initialised to their proper value once the static block is executed.

Comment: that means the accepted answer in this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block) is wrong . See the print order . The first line prints "Static initalization."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14796/discussion-between-geek-and-assylias)

Answer (score 1):

The `static` blocks execute in order of appearance (you can have multiple static blocks), when the class loader loads the class, eg. it runs before the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`Operation` constants are static fields created in the static block in the appearing order.

```
static { 
    // instantiate enum instances here
    ...
    // Initialize map from constant name to enum constant     
    for (Operation op : values())       
       stringToEnum.put(op.toString(), op);   
}
```