# Order in which static variables and methods are declared/called

Tags: java, static, runtime

I am reading a book about Java. It gives an example like this:

```
class UseStatic {
    static int a = 3;
    static int b;

    // ... some more lines  

    static {
        b = 4 * a;
    }
}
```

Then it explains this:

> As soon as the `UseStatic` class is loaded, all the `static`
>   statements are run. First, `a` is set to `3`, then the static block
>   executes, ..., and then initializes `b` to `a*4` or 12.

I wonder what really happens here with the order in which the lines are excecuted. How can it first start at the top at `static int a = 3` to only then jump over `static int b` to `static {..}` to only then jump back to static int b? How does it know this dependency?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't "jump over `static int b`", and it doesn't "jump back to `static int b`." There is nothing to "jump back" *to* because `static int b` is only a declaration, not an initialization/assigment. It declares the variable but does not assign it a value.

First `a` is declared and initialized. Then `b` is declared. Then the `static` block is executed, which assigns a value to `b`.

The Java Language Specification dictates the exact order of all of these things. See Jon Skeet's answer to [Are there any guarantees in JLS about order of execution static initialization blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3028219/139010) for more.